# Different url for different item

Tags: angular, api, http

I have a list that has 8 items.

I have to download a file on click of a specific button from HTTP response but the URL will be different for all. How can I connect them?

```html
<div class="card border-0 p-3">
  <div class="row" >
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 " *ngFor="let item of reports">
      <button class="btn btn-white w-100 lh-1  col "  [routerLink]="[ '/reports/view-reports',item.id]">
         <div class="row pl-3 lh-1"> 
            <h5 class="fw-bolder fs-5 ">{{item.heading}}</h5>
         </div>
          <div class="row pl-3 lh-1">
            <h6 class="">{{item.subheading}}</h6>
          </div>
      </button>
    </div> 
  </div>
</div>
```

HTTP request in service file -

```js
downloadReport(path: string,argument: {}): Observable<any>{
  return this.http.post(path,argument,{
    responseType: "blob",
  })
}
```

ts file -

```js
getFile() {
   let url = "https://tbapi.truckbuddy.co.in/bookingRequest/search/report"; // i want 8 different url for eachclick of button
   let body = this.reportservice.time;
   return this.reportservice.downloadReport(url,body)
      .subscribe(
        data => {
          saveAs(data);
        },
        error => {
          this.show()
          console.log(error);
        }
      )
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the `item` to your `click` handler and then pass it to the `getFile` function. Probably, you have the URL inside your `item`. It will allow you to reuse this method for all `items`:

```
 getFile(item){
       let url = item.url; // i suppose you have this url in your item,
        let body = this.reportservice.time;
        return this.reportservice.downloadReport(url,body)
        .subscribe(
          data=>{
            saveAs(data);
          },
          error=>{
            this.show()
            console.log(error);
          }
        )
      }
```